# How to fix typescript error when setting state with previous state in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this state defined

```
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = React.useState<UserInfo | undefined>()
```

And somewhere in my useEffect I am trying to set it based on previous state.

so doing this

```
                      setUserInfo(
                          (prevState) => {
                          return {
                              ...prevState,
                              ...someRef.current
                          }
                      })
```

But this fails with the following error

```
Type error: Argument of type '(prevState: any) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UserInfo'.
  Type '(prevState: any) => any' is missing the following properties from type 'UserInfo': name, age, gender
```

What is even stranger is I updated the code to return the previous state. Basically this

```
setUserInfo((prevState) => return prevState)
```

This fails with same error!

```
Type error: Argument of type '(prevState: any) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UserInfo'.
  Type '(prevState: any) => any' is missing the following properties from type 'UserInfo': name, age, gender
```

I sincerely thought this would work. I am taking the previous state and returning it but this does not compile.

If I disable the check and run the application it works as expected so this looks like typescript issue.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the return value as UserInfo.

```
setUserInfo(
  (prevState) => {
    return {
      ...prevState,
      ...someRef.current
    } as UserInfo;
  }
);
```